# How to submit a form through Javascript in an iPhone SDK application?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, code-injection

I need to post a form loaded in `UIWebview` (iPhone sdk/Objective c) through Javascript injection. I used `document.form.submit()` which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To access your form you need to pull it from the forms array. Use form's name attribute as array `key`.

This should look like:

```
document.forms['formName'].submit();
```