# Controlling Internet Explorer in order to enter username/password

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, com

I was looking into trying to get my C++ application to do the following:

1. Open internet explorer
2. Open a webpage
3. Enter a name and password into  specific forms in the webpage
4. Click the submit button on the webpage to open a new page

From my searching on the Internet it seems like using COM may make this possible, although I may be incorrect on that. I am doing my best to learn COM at the moment but some help would be great. I'm looking to do this without using MFC.

I have noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028894/automating-internet-explorer-using-c-c) question which I kind of what I am looking for but I am having trouble understanding the suggested solutions. For example, I do not have a `IWebBrowser2` option in my toolbox.

**EDIT:**

To make my question clearer, I had this task complete in a C# version by simply running a coded UI test but this will not work with C++. I am looking to open IE (not in the application itself), find the username and password forms, pass them string, then find the submit button on the page and click it.

Comment: I've deleted my answer - form filling is a much harder problem since you have to find the right boxes to fill in in the first place! I don't have an answer to it, but you might want to edit the question to make it clearer that you're looking at form submission than just HTTP basic auth.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to make my question clearer.

Comment: Is it an existing webpage? The far easier solution may be to open _another_ webpage and encode the username and authentication string* in the URL. (* Not the password itself, that wouldn't be safe, but basically a one-way, salted hash of the password to prove that you know it).

Comment: Unfortunately it is already an existing webpage. This feature seems to be not that straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible from c++. You will have to dive into the winapi to do some Keystroke stuff as well as window handling.

I'm not going to go into all of the code, but you have to do something like the following:

- Start ie (if you give it a command line arg with the webpage, it will
  open that page).
- Make sure the ie window is focused (either just wait
  if you want to keep it simple or use window's api to go through each
  open `HANDLE` and find the window you want)
- Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to send an `Alt` + `D` (to gain focus to the url bar, in firefox it will be a `CTRL + L` instead)
- Use `SendInput` and [javascript injection](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-JavaScript-Injections) to modify the DOM as necessary
- You can also [submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172385/496405) (after everything is as you want it) using the above JS injection capability.

Comment: Thanks @g19fanatic. This is an interesting approach that Ill take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to embed a web browser control in your application, and it is not straightforward (I don't think you can automate DHTML in an external instance of Internet Explorer via COM).

I see that you don't want to use MFC, and this complicates even more the problem. Perhaps you can do it via ATL, I advise against even trying to do it without a framework.

If you could use MFC, then you could use a `CDHtmlDialog` form and access the underlying COM interfaces to automate the actions.

In the past, I developed an MFC application that used HTML as its user interface, but I used the `CDHTMLView` class that you can find here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1783/Integrating-DHTML-into-MFC-Views

You can use this as an entry point for learning how to deal with DHTML events and how to play around with the `IWebBrowser2` interface.

Comment: I may have a look at doing it with ATL if its possible. Do you know of any decent site to learn some ATL ?

Comment: You can actually gain access to the DOM via IEs hwnd with MSAA; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232

Comment: @AlexK.: wow, that's cool, and MSAA is available integrated in the OS since XP. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at WebDriver which is able to do exactly what you are describing. See (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriverInternals) for more information about the InternetExplorerDriver internals. Even if you are not able to use the project directly, you can certainly browse the source to get a better idea of how what you want to do can be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for the link @Mike. Im trying to do this without framework though though so im going to try g19fanatics method at first to see if I can get the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do makes not much sense.

There are many APIs available to embed a browser view into your program. For example Qt offers this.

Then you can just do your HTTP POST request yourself and display the answer you get in your browser view.

That is a much cleaner solution.

**Pro tip: Don't use Internet Explorer.**

Comment: I do not wish to open the browser in the application firstly. I have edited my original question to make it clearer. As awoodland pointed out, I am looking to perform form filing on a webpage.